# Balancing a list on multiple columns?

Tags: lists, multicol

I would like to balance a list on N columns to take the **minimum vertical space**. From other similar questions and with struggling much I wrote this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[balancingshow]{multicol}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{keyval}

\newcounter{multicolminlines}
\setcounter{multicolminlines}{1}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\balance@columns
   {\ifnum\dimen@<\topskip
     \mult@info\@ne
       {Start value
          \the\dimen@  \space ->
          \the\topskip \space (corrected)}%
     \dimen@\topskip
   \fi}
   {\skip@\c@multicolminlines\baselineskip
   \advance\skip@-\baselineskip
   \advance\skip@\topskip
   \ifnum\dimen@<\skip@
     \mult@info\@ne
       {Start value
          \the\dimen@  \space ->
          \the\skip@ \space (corrected)}%
     \dimen@\skip@
   \fi
   }
   {\typeout{Success!}}{\patchFAILED}

\define@key{hlist@keys}{columns}{\def\hlist@columns{#1}}%
\define@key{hlist@keys}{minlines}{\def\hlist@minlines{#1}}%

\newcommand{\fixspacing}{\vspace{0pt plus 1filll}\mbox{}}

\newenvironment{hlist}[1][]{%
    \setkeys{hlist@keys}{columns=4,minlines=4,#1}
    \setcounter{multicolminlines}{\hlist@minlines}
    \begin{multicols}{\hlist@columns}

}{

    \fixspacing
    \end{multicols}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{hlist}[columns=3,minlines=10]
\begin{itemize}
    \item Gods  \item Óðinn  \item Baldur  \item Njörður  \item Freyr
    \item Týr   \item Bragi  \item Heimdal  \item Thor  \item Höðr
    \item Víðar  \item Áli or Váli  \item Ullr  \item Óðinn  \item Þór
    \item Njörðr  \item Freyr  \item Týr  \item Heimdal  \item Bragi
    \item Víðar  \item Váli  \item Ullr  \item Hœnir
\end{itemize}
\end{hlist}

\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

However, as you can see it doesn't always work. On this example, one could spare one line by using the two remaining cases on the third column.

Is this possible to make it work 100% of time?

[image]

Comment: How should it be read – horizontally first, then vertically, or the converse?

Comment: I have no constraints about that. I guess since I am using multi column, it should be read vertically first

Comment: I asked, because the other way, there are several packages (`shortlst, tasks`, also `tablists`  for enumerated lists in columns).

Comment: Why do you patch `hlist` internals? It seems you don't need to use `hlist` environment.

Comment: hlist isn’t implemented for LaTeX and doesn’t work well in HTML

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you try to do because it seems contradictory. On one hand your code tries to enforce a minimal number of lines (10 in the example) but then you write

> However, as you can see it doesn't always work. On this example, one could spare one line by using the two remaining cases on the third column.
>
> Is this possible to make it work 100% of time?

Make what 100% work all the time? By default multicol balances to the shortest possible vertical height, so if you use it without your patch you get precisely 8 items in each column. But since you requested that the columns are at least 10*\baselineskip you get 9 items because that many fit into your requested vertical size.

So the specification what want you want seems rather unclear.

Regardless of this: multicols already supports what you tried to implement it calls the counter `minrows`. So you can drop your patch and just use

```
\makeatletter

\define@key{hlist@keys}{columns}{\def\hlist@columns{#1}}%
\define@key{hlist@keys}{minlines}{\def\hlist@minlines{#1}}%

\newenvironment{hlist}[1][]{%
    \setkeys{hlist@keys}{columns=4,minlines=4,#1}%
    \setcounter{minrows}{\hlist@minlines}%
    \begin{multicols}{\hlist@columns}%

}{\end{multicols}}
\makeatother
```

with a few more `%`s than you had to avoid spurious spaces in the output. And you don't really need the `\fixspacing`because multicol offers parameters to deal with the last column.

So to me it looks as if everything is in order. If not please explain the algorithmic behavior that you are after in more detail.

Last remark, the `minrows` or your `minlines` refers to the height ofa normal text line, thus to request at least 10 items in the first column you would need to set it noticeably higher than 10.

#### Update

Since I removed your \fixedspacing command  because it should be necessary I didn't noticed that it ended in \mbox. So effectively you added another line into the multicols so that you had 3x8 items + one line. There this couldn't be balanced to 8 +8 +8 and naturally came out as 9 + 9 + 7 (as we actually had this invisible extra line in the last column).